# DYLD issue - "reason: image not found"

Tags: iphone, xcode

Weirdest SOB ever…

When i run my app on my iPhone it works perfectly. Also on lots of other iPhones. But when I try to run it on my friends iPhone (5.1.1), it starts and gets stuck immediately with the following error:

reason: image not found

Also it says it couldn't load Adsupport library. Could it be that 5.1.1 doesn't support Adsupport framework? Really?

Comment: But ***which*** image is not found? There should be the name of the library which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it, although i would really like an answer. I deleted the Adsupport framework and now it works.

I don't know what image he was talking about… Really weird.

What framework does 5.1.1 use for such things?